# How to increase the value of a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a value, called Iron, increase every second whilst in localStorage, but the value just adds a 1 on the end instead of increasing by 1.

HTML:

`<div id="iron"></div>`

Javascript:

```
var material1= "0";
localStorage.setItem("Iron","1");
window.setInterval(
     function () {
         material1 = material1 + 1;
        localStorage.setItem("Iron",material1);
         document.getElementById("iron").innerHTML = 'Current Iron Supply is: ' + localStorage.getItem("Iron");
     }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Do note: localstorage only stores _strings_. That's why you need to convert the value to a number, preferably using `Number()`, as in `Number(valueFromLocalStorage)`;

Comment: @RickardElimää I have been using localStorage as a number holder and have had no problems displaying it. Will this affect my code further on?

Comment: Javascript is very forgiving when it comes to interpret types (strings, numbers, objects, etc.) so it shouldn't be any problem, unless you use `+` to add two numbers together, as you already experienced. `localStorage` automatically turns non-strings into strings. Just try to add an object, and you will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you declared `material1` as string.
you should declare it as number like this: `var material1= 0;` and then convert it to string simply by `material1+""`

or parse `material1` to `int` before the addition